# Using Match Function for Regex in Python outputs an extra comma at the end

Tags: python, regex

I am not sure why I am getting an extra comma at the end of every output when using the Match() with Regex in python. Any ideas ? Thanks.

My Code:

```
 import re

 yyyyfile = open("yyyy.txt",'w')

 text = open('final.txt')

 for line in text: 

    x = re.match('.*?^([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])$.*', line)

    if x:

        print >> yyyyfile, x.groups()
```

Current Output:

> ('1573',)
>
> ('1595',)
>
> ('1929',)
>
> ('1933',)

Desired Output:

> ('1573')
>
> ('1595')
>
> ('1929')
>
> ('1933')

Comment: Can you show some examples of what the lines from the files look like? (from final.txt)

Comment: Nothing wrong with a tuple, is it?

Comment: What is your regex supposed to do ? It feels like '[0-9]{4}' should do the trick ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the output of re.match's groups() is all of the groups that you captured. It's a tuple.
Use `x.group(1)` or whatever instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is inside `yyyy.txt` and why you want to print it but assuming `final.txt` includes the text you should open the file with:

```
with open('final.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
```

parsing works like this:

```
import re

text = '''1235, dfx as nxcn 1229 nxcn 32 4 0 9877'''

matches = re.findall('(\d{4})', text)

for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out.
I received the following error after running the code you provided.

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: I updated my answer to provide a verifiable example. Also I simplified the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting an extra comma because you using match. The reason you get this comma is that you are printing out tuples. You can achieve the desired result like this

```
print >> yyyyfile, '(%s)' % x.group(1)
```